# Is main() a class method? (Java)

Tags: java, program-entry-point, class-method

Saw a question which detailed a simple class. The class had a basic (and non-static) method. It also had a main method.

The question asked: does this class have a class method?

Can `public static void main(String[] args){}` be considered a class method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

All static methods are called Class method, because, they belong to the Class, not to any instances of that Class.

So `public static void main(String[] args){}` also a Class method

Answer (score 4):

Not only `main()` method, every static member is belongs to `Class`  which can be shared across all the instance and not to any specific instance.

Static members bound to Class. So you can  consider that as a class method.

Prefer to read :[`Understanding Class Members`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)